# How to escape '@' character in java

Tags: java, url, ftp, cpanel, ftp-client

I am writing a method to establish a connection to FTP and while configuring the URL, my password contains '@' character, which is in conflict with the host name. How can this be resolved? Can this character be escaped?

```
URL: ftp://xyz:abc@27@www.sezin.com/home/pk09
```

Comment: Auth information in the URL was deprecated ***years*** ago and implementors in various realms (browsers, for instance) are actively removing it, as it's ridiculously insecure. Surely there's a way to connect to your FTP server and *then* supply the auth info (which is still ridiculously insecure -- this is FTP -- but may at least be supported).

Comment: Can you suggest the newer way to connect?

Comment: Are you using any library to connect to FTP?Surely there's a way to pass the credentials once the connection has been made. Refer http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/12/create-connection-to-ftp-in-java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Strongly** urge you not to do this. Quoting [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186920/how-to-escape-character-in-java/47187002#comment81322964_47186920) (in case it gets cleaned up):

> Auth information in the URL was deprecated ***years*** ago and implementors in various realms (browsers, for instance) are actively removing it, as it's ridiculously insecure. Surely there's a way to connect to your FTP server and *then* supply the auth info (which is still ridiculously insecure -- this is FTP -- but may at least be supported).

But the [user information in the authority section of a URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1) (which is deprecated) are percent-encoded, so:

```
ftp://xyz:abc%4027@www.sezin.com/home/pk09
```

`%40` is the percent-encoding value for `@`.